# Is this timer efficient?

Tags: c, timer

I found myself writing code to run at a specified frequency more than once, so I decided to make this simple timer. My main concern is that this is not the most efficient way of doing this since with `SDL` I would just ask for the time in ms and sleep in ms.

I'm storing the current time in `timer_update()` to avoid the possibility of it becoming greater than the final time and generating a huge pause since it's unsigned.

Usage is pretty simple, `timer_init()` is called once before the loop and `timer_update()` is called once at the end of every iteration.

**timer.h**

```
#ifndef TIMER_H
#define TIMER_H

typedef struct {
    double step;
    double tfinal;
} Timer;

void timer_init(Timer *timer, double hertz);
void timer_update(Timer *timer);

#endif
```

**timer.c**

```
#include "timer.h"

#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static unsigned long get_ms(void)
{
    struct timespec buffer;
    unsigned long temp;

    if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &buffer) != 0){
        perror("clock_gettime");
        return 0;
    }

    temp = buffer.tv_sec * 1000;
    temp += buffer.tv_nsec / 1000000;
    return temp;
}

static struct timespec ms_to_timespec(unsigned long ms)
{
    struct timespec temp = {ms / 1000, (ms % 1000) * 1000000};
    return temp;
}

void timer_init(Timer *timer, double hertz)
{
    timer->step = 1000 / hertz;
    timer->tfinal = get_ms() + timer->step;
}

void timer_update(Timer *timer)
{
    unsigned long now = get_ms();
    struct timespec required_sleep, rem;

    if(now < timer->tfinal){
        required_sleep = ms_to_timespec(timer->tfinal - now);
        timer->tfinal += timer->step;

        try_to_sleep:
        if(nanosleep(&required_sleep, &rem) == -1 && errno == EINTR)
            if(nanosleep(&rem, &required_sleep) == -1 && errno == EINTR)
                goto try_to_sleep;
    }

    else
        timer->tfinal += timer->step;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

> Is this timer efficient?

- Yes, but there are two optimizations that I can see.  Get rid of the `goto`
  and use a `do-while` loop.  I have noticed a slight performance
  increase when it has been written this way in other programs.

  This increase will become non-existent however if you have compiler
  optimization settings enabled.  If they are enabled, they compile
  into [the exact same assembly code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2288893/1937270).  However, I also find a loop
  more readable than a `goto`, so that is another reason to switch
  over.
- There other optimization I could see is by cleaning up your `if-else` a tiny bit (untested).  This should speed up your code a tiny bit (again, if optimizations on your compiler are enabled, your results will vary).

  ```
  if(now < timer->tfinal)
  {
      required_sleep = ms_to_timespec(timer->tfinal - now);

      // loop implementation
  }
  timer->tfinal += timer->step;
  ```

  You may wonder why this will speed up your code.  The more branches you have, the more susceptible you are to a [branch prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) failure and those failures can be expensive when it comes to efficiency.

---

A few other notes:

- Use a [designated initializer](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) to initialize a structure <sup>(C99)</sup>.

  ```
  struct timespec temp = 
  { 
      .step = ms / 1000, 
      .tfinal = (ms % 1000) * 1000000 
  };
  ```
- Group your `#include`s and `#define`s together in a more organized fashion.

  ```
  #include <time.h>  // group library headers
  #include <errno.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include "timer.h" // group user defined headers

  #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L  // group defines
  ```
- Your `!= 0` comparision check in your `if` conditional could be removed since it is redundant (the `if` will always execute if the conditional isn't equal to `0`).  However, this may increase readability to you, so it would be okay to keep it.

Answer (score 2):

this Method is kind of ugly

```
void timer_update(Timer *timer)
{
    unsigned long now = get_ms();
    struct timespec required_sleep, rem;

    if(now < timer->tfinal){
        required_sleep = ms_to_timespec(timer->tfinal - now);
        timer->tfinal += timer->step;

        try_to_sleep:
        if(nanosleep(&required_sleep, &rem) == -1 && errno == EINTR)
            if(nanosleep(&rem, &required_sleep) == -1 && errno == EINTR)
                goto try_to_sleep;
    }

    else
        timer->tfinal += timer->step;
}
```

You have nested if statements that have no braces and you only need one if statement with a slightly longer conditional. This should stop one thing from being tested twice.

```
try_to_sleep:
if((nanosleep(&required_sleep, &rem) == -1 && errno == EINTR) && nanosleep(&rem, &required_sleep)) {
    goto try_to_sleep;
}
```

The else statement bracing style should match the if statement that it is attached to, even if it is a one liner or it should truly be one line.

Using braces:

```
else {
    timer->tfinal += timer->step;
}
```

One Lined

```
else timer->tfinal += timer->step;
```

Answer (score -2):

Rather than looping around `goto`, why not calculate how much time is remaining and convert it into ticks and `sleep (ticks)`?  It would also be better to find some way to generate an event rather than lopping continuously, if timing is not very strict.

Comment: The loop is only to handle the scenario where the sleep is interrupted. The problem with `sleep()` is that it takes seconds and the timer sleeps for ms. http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep

Comment: @2013Asker, no problem, use [`usleep()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep)